# sendMail returns ResourceNotFound

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to send an email message using the Microsoft Graph REST API. My application is a service/daemon application where I am sending email on a user's behalf.

I am successfully able to obtain a token and obtain the user object such that I have the user's `id`, but when I try to use the `sendMail` API (`POST /users/{user id}/sendMail`) I receive the following error response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a911ead2-840d-4bfe-9a77-bc5000c1b749",
            "date": "2017-01-03T13:33:24"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to first create the message as a draft using `POST /users/{user id}/messages` but that also returns the exact same error. My application permissions include both `Mail.ReadWrite` and `Mail.Send`.

Comment: Can you check if the user corresponding to the id has a mailbox (i.e., access OWA)?

Comment: Looks like the issue is because I was trying to test this with my personal microsoft account and not an office 365 account. I switched to a office 365 account and it now works. I thought the graph API was suppose to work with both but I guess not.

Comment: The API supports both Microsoft account and O365 account in delegated scenario (where user does a sign in), but client_credential flow (app only) is supported only in 0365 accounts, and such a credential cannot be used to access consumer accounts.

Comment: I found this helpful article:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-my-user-id-and-why-do-i-need-it-e456eb4c-9cb9-4aa0-9d0a-923b8c53228d